# ToolStripMenuItem checked not displayed correctly

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I have set the menu item to checked with the following line in Visual Studio 2015 VB.

```
BS_ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True
```

But the tick is not displaying correctly; I get the following

[image: check box]

Can anyone please tell me how you get tick to be centered?

Any assistance is much appreciated

Comment: I think it's just visual.. I just tried with font 20 and it stays in the center.. i find no property to change that

Answer (score 5):

I have found the the issue is to do with the 'scale to fit' property just switch is to'None'

Comment: The property is "ImageScaling" change from SizeToFit to None

Comment: I have two menus side by side, and one of them is working, and for the other I had to change the ImageScaling to None

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer was to set the ImageScalingSize property of the containing ToolStrip to the size of the images on the toolstripitems. I had imagescaling set to None already. So for example my images were 16x16 and setting the imagescalingsize to 16,16 fixed the off center checkmark issue.